# React query and sse

Tags: reactjs, server-sent-events, react-query

I am a student studying about sse. I am using React Query together, but it is said that you can build sse by using the live option of useQuery among the functions of React Query, but there is no related information in the official document, so I wonder if React Query and sse are unrelated.
And I need data related to sse. Is there a document you can recommend?